# How to pass in redux toolkit more that one arguments in an action?

Tags: redux-toolkit

In the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) it is stated that you can set an action with one argument as a payload like this:

```js
incrementByAmount: (state, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    }
```

But what if I have more arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything but a segment (1:41') in ​Justin's video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lCmbth63k0)

So this is how it's done:

```js
authenticate: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{
      token: string;
      userId: string;
      expiryTime: number;
      userEmail: string
    }>) => {
      state.token = payload.token
      state.userId = payload.userId
      state.expiryTime = payload.expiryTime
      state.email = payload.userEmail
      state.triedAutoLogin = true
    },
```

Note: above the `action` is being destructured. So we do not have to do `action.payload.token`

Thanks